# Jest with WebSockets ignores messages after the first one?

Tags: javascript, websocket, jestjs

I am trying to test a WebSockets server. The onMessage handler gets called for the first time only - any further messages published to the server are not logged. Why is this happening?
`

```
     const WebSocket = require('ws');
     const ws = new WebSocket(WEBSOCKETS_ENDPOINT);

     describe('When a speed test is triggered', () => {
     test('Then AWS should send the result to the client', done => {
        ws.on('open', async () => {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                message: 'start-speed-test-rbsid',
                data: RBSID,
                platform: "android"
            }));
                ws.on('message', data => {
                    data = JSON.parse(data)
                    // this gets called only once - any further messages published from the server are not logged
                    console.log(data)
                });
        })
     })
     afterAll(() => ws.close())
```

});

Message data should be logged on every message that was published

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem using you code against echo server.

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');

describe('When a speed test is triggered', () => {
  test('Then AWS should send the result to the client', done => {
    ws.on('open', async () => {
      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        message: 'start-speed-test-rbsid',
        data: 'RBSID',
        platform: "android"
      }));
      ws.on('message', data => {
        // this gets called only once - any further messages published from the server are not logged
        console.log(data)
      });

      ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        message: 'start-speed-test-rbsid',
        data: 'RBSID',
        platform: "android"
      }));
    })
  })
  afterAll(() => ws.close());
});
```

Another thing is, if you are writing unit test, and the test involves network IO, it is usually suggested to mock the network component.

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');

jest.mock('ws', () => {
  class MockedWebSocket {}

  return MockedWebSocket;
});

console.log(WebSocket); // mocked
```

Comment: What is the point of mocking a 'fake' component, should it not test the actual/real component? Is that what is called integration test?

Comment: Regarding unit test, there are a few criteria. 1. it is meant to test a unit of work, without mocking out the lib, you are also testing `ws`, sometime it could be an issue of dependencies but you don't really want it to fail your test, You might need a workaround tho. 2. It need to be fast so that you could run it over and over again, without slowing down your development. And, network IO response time, depending on network condition and geographic location, usually takes around 100ms, this extra time add up if you have a lot of similar tests, and you run them frequent enough

Comment: integration test is where you try to put all the components together and see if they work, usually without actual network IO or disk IO, still separating backend and frontend. end to end (e2e) test is where you are trying to test you application in real world scenario. <offtopic>people usually suggest to have >80% unit test coverage, 10~20 for integration and e2e. some people instead suggest to have 100% integration test on public API, it is another topic.</offtopic>